# How to make items transparent in GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm working on a `GridView`, containing 3 columns and 6 rows. I only want to display the items which do not contain an empty string, say setting the `""`-items transparent. How could I achieve this?

Code of `main.java`:

```
final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] {
                "A" , "B" , "C" ,
                "D" , "E" , "F" ,
                "" , "^" , "" ,
                "<" , "" , ">" ,
                "" , "!" , "" ,
                "G" , "H" , "I"};


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ButtonsAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));
```

Code of the `XML`-file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons_background">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:textSize="27px"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT:**

`ButtonsAdapter.java`:

```
public class ButtonsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final String[] mobileValues;

    public ButtonsAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buttons_commands, null);

            // set value into textview
            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
            textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

            String mobile = mobileValues[position];
        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mobileValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's in your `ButtonsAdapter`. you probably have a `getView` there, just add a `view.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);` toward the end (don't forget to have an `else` block to revert the visibility back to VISIBLE, too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Add this in your adapter's `getView()` method

```
String val = ((GridView)parent).getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)gridView.findViewById(R.id.item_container); // add this id in your xml
if(val.length() == 0)
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.transparent);
else
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttons_background);
```

Also add this in your `colors.xml`

```
<color name="transparent">#00ffffff</color>
```

**Solution 2**

```
String val = ((GridView)parent).getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
if(val.length() == 0)
    gridView.setVisiblility(View.INVISIBLE);// or View.GONE; as per your choice
else
   gridView.setVisiblility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**Solution 3** Depends if you DO NOT need those blank string later

Change the String array to a ArrayList and remove all the blank strings

Comment: how do I add this id in the XML file: `R.id.item_Container` ?

Comment: Add `android:id="@+id/item_container"` in the linear layout of the xml

Comment: ok, added the id. But the IDE struggles with the following line: `String val = parent.getView().getItem(position).toString();` : Cannot resolve method getView(). Any idea?

Comment: Please check my code its `parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();` Its `getAdapter()` not `getView()`

Comment: checked it, but now it cannot resolve `getAdapter()` -.-

Comment: I am sorry my fault. use this `((GridView)parent).getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();`